# Leveraging hierarchical data in a GBM

Tags: multilevel-analysis, boosting

A challenge that I encounter in a lot of modelling, is how to best handle hierarchical data for making prediction.

A simple example of this is a basic (binary) classification problem, where I am predicting whether or not someone will purchase a product base on a variety of features. Included in this feature-set are:

- City
- State
- Metro/Rural

Clearly there is some degree of overlap between **city** and both **state** and **metro/rural**, as all cities fall under a hierarchy of both **state** and **metro/rural**.

Generally speaking, I have found GBMs to have the best predictive performance for the type of modelling that I'm doing, but haven't tested anything that specifically accounts for the hierarchical relationships that exist within the data.

I've struggled to try and find answers, as Google mostly returns results for hierarchical classification (classifying whether an animal is a cat vs dog, then classifying what breed of dog it is).

Any suggestions on how where I should start looking?